# how to check WebSocket running status in node server from another node server (on localhost)

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have 2 node servers named **server1** and **server2**. From **server1** I want to check whether **websocket** of **server2** is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

enable CORS in server2. you could create an html page to be rendered by server1, on the html page enable websocket, make sure the url of the websocket is pointing to server2, then use the send() method to send a message form the page to server2, on server2 listen for incoming message from websockets and respond appropriately back.. use send() and emit() methods respectively